How can I safely store untrusted files?
Is it possible to store untrusted files in Linux safely? My assumption is that I would create a new user to store them and run:
chmod rw------- <directory>

However, is there anything else I can do to evade any potential concerns with these files.
I do not need to execute them. My only need for them is to download and read data on the files.
Is there anything else I should be weary of? Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

What sort of risk are you concerned about? If you're not executing the files, they can't "do" anything.

I would put them in a .tar file.  Then you can use archivemount in read-only mode if you are paranoid about browsing them.  But larsks is right, unless you open a file, there's no risk.

@larsks this is precisely my question. I am less than familiar with data security and as such want to confirm no other tasks are needed and/or risk.

You need to define what risks you want to address

What do you "untrust" these files to do? Are they executable programs or scripts that might make your system misbehave? Are they simple text files  containing Government Secret information, that it's illegal for you to posess? Spend some thought time on a Threat and Risk Assessment before speending effort on countermeasures.

If you're not executing the files, they can't "do" anything.  ...  it is simply not a matter of files executing or not with regards to malware


I do not need to execute them. My only need for them is to download and read data on the files.

# in /etc/fstab have the mount be as such...

UUID = <whatever>   /data    <filesystem>  defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec   0 0

mount your partition as noexec.  And then afterwards once your files are written to that location then remount the partition as read-only via ...noexec,ro
obviosly this means you need your <directory> on a sepearate partition other than /.
After that, I suppose making the file permissions both user and group owned by some protected user account with minimal permissions & privileges and then doing chmod 600 on them is the most secure you'd be able to get them from that perspective, along with that folder being 700 {you need the folder executable so you can cd into it}
And after that I suppose making use of selinux to impose further restrictions on said files/folders/user account in some fashion.

Do you know how to do it with the mount CLI? Having to alter /etc/fstab is a bit cumbersome.

first  lsblk -o size,fstype,model,name,uuid  to identify the uuid of the partition you want... which will also identify as dev/sdb1 for example... the b and 1 there is what will vary...

can be as simple as mount -o defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec  /dev/sdb1  /restricted 

mount -o remount,defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec,ro  /dev/sdb1  /restricted

change /dev/sdb1  to UUID=abc123 for whatever the uuid shows as via lsblk, if you desire to mount via uuid, which i strongly recommend if you are putting this in /etc/fstab for auto mounting when booting.  But if you are going to do it manually then via by-name as /dev/sdb1 is fine unless you don't mind typing extra to do the by-UUID way

putting it in /etc/fstab is no more cumbersome, and simply putting a # in front of the line to comment it out for when u don't want it automounting during boot is a great place to keep it for reference... if you can't remember /etc/fstab you got bigger problems.

Thanks for the answer. Using mount directly means that you don't have to modify a file, that's one step less (I use the fish shell so I can run a previous command easily). I suggest to add this alternative method in the answer directly.

this might be optimal for me because i am using an external drive. thank you so much

Edit:
Credit to @u1686_grawity
We need executable privileges to access directories. As such, this is more appropriate:
find <directory>/ -type f -exec chmod a-x {} +


Original Message
As stated in the comments, files can't really "do" anything without being executed. As such the following command should suffice:
chmod rw------- <directory>

Replace <directory> with the directory of the files~~

It would make more sense to set -x on the files themselves, not on the directory. You need +x on directories to actually access their contents.

@u1686_grawity ahhh so instead i would do: chmod rw------- <directory>/*
Or is it possible to set chmod to have default privileges for all files under a certain directory?

find thedir/ -type f -exec chmod a-x {} + would be the typical way of writing it.
